# Follow org links in current buffer with ivy

Tags: org-mode, ivy, counsel, org-roam

How can I follow org links in the current buffer using ivy?   This is similar functionality to `m` (`M-x Info-menu`) in info with ivy/counsel installed.

The command should list with ivy everything that org considers a link in the current buffer, and when a link is selected, it should navigate there.

Primarily I want to use this for internal navigation in org-roam, not for browsing to web links.  I'm aware that org-roam has its own link navigation functions that uses the org-roam sqlite database, but I want a shorter list of candidates: just those in the current file.  When I have something like this, I imagine tweaking it to work for the org-roam backlinks buffer also, but the focus of this question is the general question for org, not org-roam in particular.

Comment: So you want a function that produces the list of links in the current file?

Comment: Produces that list of links and hooks that up to ivy, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might leverage what org-roam does and write a function with a more limited query that gets the current buffer-file-name and limits result by that.

Alternatively, here is an independent approach that might work for you.

```
(defun follow-buffer-link ()
  (interactive)
  (ivy-read "Link: " (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'link
               (lambda (lnk)
             (list (org-element-property :raw-link lnk) lnk)))
        :action (lambda (candidate)
              (save-excursion
            (goto-char (org-element-property :begin (second candidate)))
            (org-open-at-point)))))
```